# Confirm active-session by asking IDP

Tags: session, saml-2.0, adfs

**Use Case**

To minimize the need for users to perform *Sing On* I would like to run an active session for as long as possible.

The user does SSO and SP allows the user to have access until the point where IDP says - session (or account) is not active anymore.

SP would need to ask IDP - is session active for this user?

**My question**

Is the above possible and if so what is the best practice of implementing SP asking IDP of session (account) activity for a specific user?

As I imagine, after successful initial authentication SAML Response body would hold a session-token which can be stored against a user. The same session-token can be used to query IDP to understand if session (account) is still active. However what service would that be?

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the SAML specification that you can use to query account status.

What you can do is use the `isPassive` flag on a SAML request to see if there's an ongoing SSO session at the user's IDP. You could ask the IDP to modify its behavior and return account status instead but that would be a one-to-one agreement outside of the standard.

The alternative is to use a backchannel call with a protocol like SCIM, see:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.4.1, that would allow you to query the status of a users's account with a REST call. But of course that is a different protocol than SAML and something that must be supported by the IDP.

Comment: Thanks, @hans-z. I had a suspicion that there's nothing in the SAML specs allowing this. If you have a moment, I would like to pick your brain regarding isPassive. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179235/saml-ispassive Alternatively, I'm interested to know what type of respond IDP produces if isPassive is sent from SP compared to not having isPassvie flag?